Some Questions about Eguchi-Hanson metric
I'm trying to understand a Ricci-flat metric---Eguchi-Hanson metric recently. As I know, it's a metric defined on $\{(z^1)^2+(z^2)^2+(z^3)^2=1\}\subset \mathbb{C}^3$.
(1) I wonder to understand the complex structure on this surface. I only know it's smooth and not biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$. Can anyone tells me more, like a good holomorphic atlas or its topology?
(2) I wonder to get a good reference about this metric. Thanks in advance.

I don't know about your background, but this paper seems to contains some very nice description of the metric and, at the very least, gives formulae for the curvature tensor and so on.

To complement Arctic Char's reference: The Eguchi-Hanson metric "lives" on the total space of the cotangent bundle of the complex projective line, which is not biholomorphic to the complex quadric mentioned, but might well be diffeomorphic. (The cotangent bundle contains a compact curve, the zero section, so does not holomorphically embed in any complex Cartesian space.) It may not be widely appreciated that the fiber metric of Eguchi-Hanson isometrically embeds in Euclidean three-space as a surface of rotation. It looks like an asymptotically-conical bowl. [1/2]

My favorite description comes from what Michael Singer and I call the "momentum construction." A complete account can be found in Trans. AMS 354 6 (2002), 2285--2395. If time permits I'll type up a capsule account for this metric. [2/2]
